# efficiently implementing takeByKey for spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, functional-programming, rdd

I have an RDD of type `RDD[(k:Int,v:String)]`.  I want to take up to 1000 tuples for each key `k` so that I have `[(k,v)]` where no key appears more than 1000 times.  **Is there a way to do this where I can avoid the performance penalty of calling groupBy first**?  I cannot figure out a good way aggregate the values in a way to avoids a full groupBy which is causing my job to fail.

The naive approach:

```
def takeByKey(rdd: RDD[(K,V)], n: Int) : RDD[(K,V)] = {
    rdd.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.take(n)).flatMap(_._2)
}
```

I am looking for a more-efficient approach that avoids groupBy:

```
takeByKey(rdd: RDD[(K,V)], n: Int) : RDD[(K,V)] = {
    //use reduceByKey, foldByKey, etc..??
}
```

Here is the best solution I have developed so far but it doesn't type-check..

```
def takeByKey(rdd: RDD[(K,V)], n: Int) : RDD[(K,V)] = {
      rdd.foldByKey(List[V](), ((acc, elem) => if (acc.length >= n) acc else elem._2 :: acc)).flatMap(t => t._2.map(v => (t._1, v)))
}
```

**Edit.**
I have come up with a slightly better solution that appears to be working:

```
takeByKey(rdd: RDD[(K,V)], n: Int) : RDD[(K,V)] = {
    rdd.mapValues(List(_))
       .reduceByKey((x,y) => if(x.length >= n) x 
                             else if(y.length >= n) y 
                             else (x ++ y).take(n))
       .flatMap(t => t._2.map(v => (t._1, v)))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current solution is a step in the right direction but it is still quite inefficient for at least three reasons:

- `mapValues(List(_))` creates a huge number of temporary `List` objects
- `length` for linear `Seq` like `List` is *O(N)*
- `x ++ y` once again creates a large number of temporary objects

The simplest you can include is to replace `List` with mutable buffer with constant time `length`. One possible example would be something like this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

rdd.aggregateByKey(ArrayBuffer[Int]())(
  (acc, x) => if (acc.length >= n) acc else acc += x,
  (acc1, acc2) => {
    val (xs, ys) = if (acc1.length > acc2.length) (acc1, acc2) else (acc2, acc1)
    val toTake = Math.min(n - xs.length, ys.length)
    for (i <- 0 until toTake) {
      xs += ys(i)
    }
    xs         
  }
)
```

On a side note you can replace:

```
.flatMap(t => t._2.map(v => (t._1, v)))
```

with

```
.flatMapValues(x => x)  // identity[Seq[V]]
```

It won't affect performance but it is slightly cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best solution I came up with so far

```
takeByKey(rdd: RDD[(K,V)], n: Int) : RDD[(K,V)] = {
    rdd.mapValues(List(_))
       .reduceByKey((x,y) => if(x.length >= n) x 
                             else if(y.length >= n) y 
                             else (x ++ y).take(n))
       .flatMap(t => t._2.map(v => (t._1, v)))
}
```

It doesn't run out of memory and die like the groupByKey approach does, but it is still slow.